# Countdown from 60 by increments of 5

Tags: jquery, ajax

I found several answers, but there must be something I am not understanding.

I need to put a x 1 minute v in increments of 5 seconds, as in, 60 fade to 55 fade to 50, etc.

The page where this goes is loading data from php/ajax, but I cannot figure out if this part is in conflict or what.

Here is what I have:

```
var counter = 60;
$('#seks').html(counter);
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    counter=counter-5;
    $('#seks').fadeOut(slow).html(counter).fadeIn(slow);.
    if (counter == 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 5000);
```

A interval function update from the db, like this:

```
setInterval(function() {

    var fadeInData = function fadeInData() { $('#updateshere').fadeIn(); }
    var loadData = function loadData() {    $('#updateshere').load('http://launchpad-001.com/_firingRange/danTestPageHits/', fadeInData); }
    $('#updateshere').fadeOut(loadData);   
}, 60000);
```

I know this is simple, and I have more complicated stuff running, you can seen some at this link, where I need to put this countdown clock.

But, there must be something I don't know because I cannot get this to work.

This is the html to update:

```
<div id="seks"></div>
```

To me, this looks like it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 60;

    $('#seks').html(counter);
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        counter=counter-5;
        $('#seks').fadeOut(slow).html(counter).fadeIn(slow);.
        if (counter == 5) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 5000);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt was close, but didn't take into account the idea of using the callback from the fx queue calls (fadeIn, fadeOut). Also keep in mind that `slow` needs to be the string `"slow"` because that is what jquery expects, not `slow` which would refer to a variable (assuming you don't have `var slow = 1000` somewhere).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var counter = 60;

 var seks = $('#seks').html(counter);//save copy to reduce querying
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
    counter -= 5;
    seks.fadeOut('slow',function(){//use callback after animation
     seks.html(counter).fadeIn('slow');//now fade back in once out is done
    });
    if (counter == 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
 }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: ahgh quickest on the draw :)

Comment: Not only an answer, but exactly the explanation I needed.  I don't quite understand it yet, but i know enough to know that makes sense and is something I am oblivious, but I will go through the reference material and now that I know what I am looking for, I am sure I will understand this.  Thank you.